# (Solved) How can I power circuits that loop on themselves and do not have an input?

Tags: transistors, capacitor, current, resistors, logic-gates

I found these circuits online:

[image: circuit]

They are supposed to be the simplest square wave oscillator you can make.

What can I do to actually make them work?

They don't have an input for power and do not have the required input to get them going. How can I supply that?

This is another example:

[image: circuit]

Where can I supply the current from? If I keep supplying it, it would probably make the circuit always have the NOT gate active and it would stop it from working properly. Do I need to send a pulse of some sort?

Edit: I now realize that these are NOT gates and they will invert the 0V that is coming in through the base. Before creating the post, I thought that with no input the circuit wouldn't even start running, but that is not the case. I built the third circuit from the images with a 10K ohm resistor and a 100uF capacitor. This should work, but it doesn't.

Solved! Sorry for this post! I probably should've made it solved the moment I realized my mistake. Thank you for your help, but I don't know what I was expecting!

Comment: The real digital components that you would use to build these circuits have power supply pins that are normally not shown/drawn.

Comment: A logic gate doesn't have a "base."  It has inputs.

Comment: What logic gates are you actually using?

Comment: @Kartman I am using two transistors as NOT gates.

Comment: No schematic? You’re forcing us to guess. My guess is your single transistor not gate is not equivalent to something like a 74HC04 as it has no active means of driving the output high. Your usual logic gate has a push-pull/totem pole output that actively drives to output high and low. Your oscillator circuit requires this.

Comment: How can we provide a factual answer without seeing the actual circuit you are trying to use?

Comment: This should work somewhat if using gates with an inverting Schmitt-trigger input (some internal *positive* feed-back).

Comment: A logic gate built from discrete transistors will not behave in the same way as a logic gate IC. Show us the actual circuits you've built, not what you think the approximate equivalent is.

Answer (score 3):

You are showing us a *logic diagram*.

Actual Vcc and Vss is delivered to the IC chips on separate pins.  Those are omitted from logic diagrams because everyone knows every chip receives Vcc and Vss, so it would only clutter the drawing to show them.

Same as with most household electrical diagrams, safety ground will be omitted from the wiring diagram, even though you connect every ground to every other ground and every device when you actually install it.

Comment: I understand that and I already have the logic gate powered. If I touch a resistor connecting to the base of one of the NOT gates, it turns on the led, but when I take it off the entire circuit just stops working. There is no power to the led.

Comment: @RadoslavL, if your circuit is built of discrete components then you need to post your actual schematic. There's a CircuitLab editor button on the editor toolbar.